# the series $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2+x^2}, x \in \mathbb{R}$ converges uniformly in $\mathbb{R}$ to a continuous $s(x)$

Tags: analysis

I am asked to show that the series $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2+x^2}, x \in \mathbb{R}$$
converges uniformly in $\mathbb{R}$ to a $s(x)$ and that $s(x)$ is continuous.

That's what I have tried:

$$n^2+x^2 \geq n^2 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{n^2+x^2} \leq \frac{1}{n^2} \Rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2+x^2} \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2} < +\infty$$

So,from the Weierstrass criterion, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2+x^2} \overset{ uniformly}{=} s(x)$.

As $\frac{1}{n^2+x^2}$ continuous and the convergence is uniform, $s(x)$ is also continuous in $\mathbb{R}$.

Could you tell me if it is right or if I have done something wrong?

Comment: You're absolutely right!

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane Nice,thank you!!!

Comment: this seems to converge at 
$$\frac{\pi  x \coth (\pi  x)-1}{2 x^2}$$

Comment: How did you find it?